# How to access python namedtuple from matlab

Tags: python, matlab

I am accessing a python function from a library where the library returns values in a collections.namedtuple. How can I access the elements of the named tuple directly from MATLAB? I am using Python 2.7 as my MATLAB version is not compatible with Python 3.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is not supported.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/limitations-to-python-support.html